# I was admitted in Mathematics

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

```
I was admitted in Mathematics.
```

I am confused about  the preposition.

Comment: More context is needed. Do you mean "the Mathematics Program" like in some university? Mathematics itself doesn't admit people.

Comment: It looks like an abbreviated form of 'into the Faculty of Mathematics'. I suspect that the previous context would make the meaning clear to a native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that statement is not grammatically correct.

Some options to make it correct:

- I was admitted to the Mathematics program.
- I was accepted to the Mathematics major.
- I was allowed into the Mathematics department.